# Failed to find query with ID:[xx]

Tags: c#, odbc, ignite

I'm getting an error when running a SQL DDL statement through an ODBC connection in .Net Core.

I'm using a fresh default Ignite (v2.7) instance connected from .Net Core (v2.2) via an OdbcConnection (System.Data.Odbc v4.5.0).

Stack Trace:

```
2019-56-04 10:56:57.622 [ERROR] CREATE TABLE X (Id varchar(255) not null, Value int, PRIMARY KEY (Id));CREATE TABLE Y (Id varchar(255) not null, Value int, PRIMARY KEY (Id));
2019-56-04 10:56:57.710 [ERROR] ERROR [HY000] Failed to find query with ID: 0
2019-56-04 10:56:57.718 [ERROR]    at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.NextResult(Boolean disposing, Boolean allresults)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.FirstResult()
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I noticed that if I separated the two statements into separate calls to ExecuteNonQuery, it did work, so I'm assuming Ignite doesn't like multiple statements when it's getting the number of records affected.

I found a similar [issue](http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Failed-to-find-query-with-ID-0-td18165.html) from v2.3, but I think this is different, and I'm getting it in v2.7.

Reproducer:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace IgniteMultistatementReproducer {
    internal class Program {
        private static void Main(string[] args) {
            try {
                using (var conn = new OdbcConnection($"DRIVER={{Apache Ignite}};ADDRESS=localhost:10800;")) {
                    conn.Open();
                    var cmd = new OdbcCommand {
                        CommandText = "CREATE TABLE X (Id varchar(255) not null, Value int, PRIMARY KEY (Id));CREATE TABLE Y (Id varchar(255) not null, Value int, PRIMARY KEY (Id));",
                        Connection = conn
                    };
                    var numRecordsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Num Records Affected: {numRecordsAffected}");
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide C# code sample as well?

Comment: @isapego Added code to reproduce the issue.